# Mongodb cant connect db with invalid name

Tags: mongodb

I accidentally created a database with name having an umlaut character "ü".
I supposed to have database name "DBBürth" but it was created with the name "DBB?urth".
Now I can't list all of the databases because one of the database has invalid name. I am trying to delete that database but can't use or connect to that database.

```
use DBBürth
db.dropDatabase()

use DBB?rth
db.dropDatabase()
```

But those commands were unsuccessful because the database was not deleted. If only I could determine the name or properly connect to that database, I will be able to drop it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have successfully deleted the database by browsing to mongodb ns files /data/db and delete the files of the database that has an invalid name.